# nVidia Driver - Laptop Lid closed in docking station, but Laptop monitor used

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I updated my nVidia drivers for my laptop and now when I put it in my docking station it is trying to use the laptop monitor as one of my two monitors (instead of my two actual monitors).

So it should be showing on two monitors on my desk, but it shows on one monitor and my laptop.

Just to be clear, the second monitor (the one that is not getting the display like it should) is working fine.  It shows the display on that monitor while it is booting up, but after it boots, it turns off and says "No DVI input".

Is there a way to say: Use the other monitor!

Specs:
Dell Precision M90
XP Pro SP3
Quadro 1500m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for a three-way toggle between internal display, external display and both simultaneously.